# JS clone objects using spread operator and change one field

Tags: javascript, object, spread-syntax

Say I have an object: `{a: 'A', b: 'B', c: 'C'}` and I want to create a new object from it that would have the same values except I want to set `c: 'D'`.

What is the syntax for that?
I tried something like:

`{c: 'D', ...rest} = {...foo}`

But it is not a valid syntax.

Comment: @MaheerAli I don't want to modify foo. I want to create a new object using foo values.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using spread operator to update an object value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49491393/using-spread-operator-to-update-an-object-value) and [modifying an object using … in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55680620) and [Update Multiple Properties of an object with spread operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41878169)

Answer (score 14):

You spread syntax on right hand side.

**Note:** Use Spread Operator first then set the new property. For example `{c:'D',...foo}` will not work.

```js
let foo = {a: 'A', b: 'B', c: 'C'};
let res = {...foo, c:'D'};
console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 8):

You would write your code like this:

```js
var obj1 = {a: 'A', b: 'B', c: 'C'}
var obj2 = {...obj1, c: 'D'}
console.log(obj2)
```

Writing `...obj1` will fill `obj2` with `obj1`'s contents, and writing `c: 'D'` will overwrite `c: 'c'`.

> Note, ordering is important, as maheer mentioned, because the object will be written in order, from each property, which can mess up ordering of keys, and setting incorrect values:

```js
var obj = {a: 'A', b: 'B', c: 'C'}
var ex1 = {...obj, c: 'D'}
var ex2 = {c: 'D', ...obj}
var ex3 = {c: 'D', ...obj, c: 'E'}

console.log('Example 1:', ex1)
console.log('Example 2:', ex2)
console.log('Example 3:', ex3)
```

Answer (score -2):

Use the spread operator and put your property you wanna change after it

```js
let foo = {a : "Other A", b : "OtherB", c : "OtherC"}
let obj = {a: 'A', b: 'B', c: 'C'}
    obj = {...foo, c : 'D'};
    
    console.log(obj);
```